Spin-Spin Correlation Function
Consider a generic magnetic system of $N$ spin; let $M(\{s_i\})=\sum_i s_i$ be the magnetization of the system. Defining the spin-spin correlation function as
$$
g_{ij}=\langle s_i s_j \rangle -\langle s_i\rangle \langle s_j\rangle \,,
$$
is then
$$
\sum_{ij}g_{ij}=\langle M^2 \rangle -\langle M\rangle ^2\
$$
always (I mean independently of translation-invariance assumption) verified? Then, if the system is homogeneous, $\langle s_i \rangle=m$ does not depend on the site and we can also write $\langle M \rangle = Nm$.
This question is a reformulation of a doubt I had while studying from the notes of a course, but related to the density-density correlation function. The fact that
$$\int_{V} d\vec{x}_1 \int_{V} d\vec{x}_2\, g(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2)=\int_{V} d\vec{x}_1 \int_{V} d\vec{x}_2\, \left[\langle \rho(\vec{x}_1)\rho(\vec{x}_2)\rangle - \langle\rho(\vec{x}_1)\rangle\langle\rho(\vec{x}_2)\rangle\right]=\langle N^2\rangle-\langle N\rangle^2$$, i.e. the double-integral of $g$ is the variance of the particle number, is it independent of translation invariance? The invariance, however, becomes important to recover the fluctuations in terms of density, through the fluctuation-dissipation relation (because in this hypothesis I can write $\rho=\langle N \rangle/V$). This seems to me also coherent with H.E. Stanley, Introduction to phase transition and critical phenomena.
I have one more question: I heard at lesson, evaluating $\sum_{ij}g(i,j)$, that “$\sum_{i}s_i\neq\sum_{j}s_j$ on a finite lattice, then $\langle\sum_{i}s_i\rangle\neq\langle\sum_{j}s_j\rangle$, and consequently we can recover the $\langle M\rangle^2$”; but I can't understand why (a friend of mine says why we need to take the edge into account).
Probably he referred to $\sum_{<ij>}s_i$ and $\sum_{<ij>}s_j$; we were applying Weiss theory to $\mathcal{H}_{\text{Ising}}$, i.e. $s_i=s_i-m+m$ and $s_j=s_j-m+m$:
$$H(\{s\})=-J\sum_{<ij>}(s_i-m)(s_j-m)-J\underbrace{\sum_{<ij>}(s_i-m)m}_{(a)}-{J\sum_{<ij>}m^2}-J\underbrace{\sum_{<ij>}(s_j-m)m}_{(b)}+H\sum_i s_i$$
and then he said that (a) and (b) are equal only in the Thermodynamic Limit. But also in this case, in my opinion, the two sums are equal. The only difference is that they are not equal to $\frac{z}{2}\sum_{i}s_i$, with $z$ coordination number, on a finite net. Is it right?

Since
$$
M^2
=
\biggl( \sum_{i} s_i \biggr)^2
=
\biggl( \sum_{i} s_i \biggr)\biggl( \sum_{j} s_j \biggr)
=
\sum_{i,j} s_i s_j,
$$
and
$$
\langle M\rangle^2
=
\biggl( \sum_{i} \langle s_i\rangle \biggr)^2
=
\biggl( \sum_{i} \langle s_i\rangle \biggr)\biggl( \sum_{j} \langle s_j\rangle \biggr)
=
\sum_{i,j} \langle s_i\rangle\langle s_j\rangle,
$$
we get
$$
\langle M^2 \rangle - \langle M \rangle^2
=
\sum_{i,j} \langle s_i s_j \rangle - \sum_{i,j} \langle s_i \rangle \langle s_j\rangle
= \sum_{i,j} g(i,j).
$$
This does not require translation invariance and applies to arbitrary finite systems.
Translation invariance may become useful (although not strictly speaking necessary) in order to define the relevant quantities in the thermodynamic limit.
Concerning your last question, a bit more context would be required to guess what was the original claim. But you're right that, in a finite system, spins at the boundary have less neighbors than spins in the bulk (well, except if you use periodic boundary condition, since then there is no boundary).
Addendum following the additional context in the OP:
I can only guess, unfortunately. Observe that
$$
\sum_{<ij>} f(i) = \frac12 \sum_i \sum_{j\sim i} f(i) = \sum_i \frac{d_i}2 f(i),
$$
where $d_i$ is the degree of the site $i$ (i.e., the number of neighbors of $i$) and $\sum_{j\sim i}$ is the sum over all neighbors of $i$. For a finite system, the degrees of boundary vertices is different from the degree of bulk vertices (the latter are equal to the coordination number $z$ of the corresponding lattice). So, I'd agree with you: he probably meant that this sum is not equal to $\frac z2\sum_{i} f(i)$. However, replacing $f(i)$ by $f(j)$ above does not change anything (you just interchange the roles of $i$ and $j$ in the computation).
Concerning fluctuation/dissipation theorem: if you simply mean the identity $\chi=\beta (\langle M^2\rangle -\langle M\rangle^2)$, then the latter always hold, as long as you only work with finite systems.  You don't need translation invariance (it's just a direct computation of the second derivative of the free energy with respect to $h$). However, if you want to consider the thermodynamic limit, then your life is easier if you assume translation invariance (say, to prove existence of the limiting free energy density).

Thanks for your answer, professor. Concerning the last point, I added something to the main question. For the rest, it seems to me that the fluctuation-dissipation theorem is more generic than the proofs that I find in books, in the sense that to obtain the local response functions linked to corr. functions I have to exploit the translation invariance, but nothing prevents me from writing a fluctuation-dissipation relation for an extensive susceptibility. In this case I do not need the hypothesis $g\equiv f(|\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2|)$. Excuse me if I am taking advantage of your kindness.
